# Cannot upgrade to PHP 7 on Sierra

Tags: php, macos, macos-sierra

I can't seem to upgrade to PHP 7 since upgrading OS X to Sierra. I've tried following [various tutorials](https://developerjack.com/blog/2015/12/11/Installing-PHP7-with-homebrew/) but this I can't seem to do it.

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mike$ brew tap homebrew/versions
Updating Homebrew...
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mike$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
Updating Homebrew...
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mike$ brew unlink php56
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.29_5... 17 symlinks removed
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:~ mike$ brew install php70
Error: /usr/local/opt/php70 is not a valid keg
```

Can someone point out what is wrong?

Update...

In `/usr/local/Cellar`

[image]

Comment: did you look in Cellar ?  could there be a php71 (since you did not specify the one you wanted).

Comment: Couple of things, try a brew update first. If that fails please run brew doctor and post the response.

Answer (score 2):

Go to folder: /usr/local/opt/ 
Delete php70 folder.
Then run: `brew install php70` or `brew install php70 --with-httpd24`

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it. A shame the error message is so misleading.